# Highchart datetime-XAxis export is different from the page

Tags: highcharts, export, react-highcharts

I use `reflow = true` to make sure my chart fit the width of the container div on resizing the window, so the XAxis will also change.
But when export, different size charts exported as the same size, and the XAxis are not as same as shown.

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8zb9k5j6/

Is there any way to solve this? Thanks for your help

For example:

1. Full-screen, my XAxis is (4.Dec, 20.Dec, 3.Jan, 31.Jan, 14.Feb, 28.Feb)
   [Full-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZwdf.png)
2. When export as PNG(or whatever), my XAxis is (4.Dec, 20.Dec, 3.Jan, 31.Jan, 14.Feb, 28.Feb), that's what I want.
   [Full-screen-export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaPCb.png)
3. When I zoom out of the browser, the size of the chart will also decrease, my XAxis is (Dec'21, Jan'22, Feb'22)
   [small-size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uagrU.png)
4. When export as PNG(or whatever), my XAxis is (4.Dec, 20.Dec, 3.Jan, 31.Jan, 14.Feb, 28.Feb), **that's not what I want, I want (Dec'21, Jan'22, Feb'22).**
   [small-size-export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhcZA.png)

Answer (score 0):

The chart export function renders the chart from initial - any changes, like zoom, extremes changes are not applied to the chart config. If you want to apply those changes you will need to add custom logic in the load event, like:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load() {
                const chart = this;
                
                if (chart.renderer.forExport) {
                    console.log('aaply custom changes')
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wfua8rye/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still have no idea how to handle this logic...

Comment: You need to set inside this if the same extremes for both axes that have been applied after zoom